# get Edm from InputStream/String Olingo4

Tags: java, rest, olingo, odata4j

In Olingo 2 I could do this:

```
Edm metadataEdm = EntityProvider.readMetadata(metadataInputStream, false); //metadataInputStream is java.io.InputStream
```

From what I have read in Olingo 4, you can do this:

```
ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getClient();

            String serviceRoot = "http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc";
            EdmMetadataRequest request
               = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getMetadataRequest(serviceRoot);

            ODataRetrieveResponse<Edm> response = request.execute();
```

But in my project I can only use `HTTPClient` for any network calls - which means I can't use `ODataClient client`.

From `HttpClient` I can get the `InputStream`.  Is there a way (as shown above for Olingo 2) to get the `Edm` object from InputStream in Olingo 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do this in Olingo 4 using the `ODataReader`.It accepts input stream in method `Edm readMetadata(InputStream input);`

Your code above can be modified in the following way to achieve the same result.

```
ODataReader reader = ODataClientFactory.getClient().getReader();

String serviceRoot = "http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata";

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serviceRoot);

httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml"); // Looks like version 4.4.0 of OData client only supports xml format for metadata

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
Edm edm = reader.readMetadata(response.getEntity().getContent());
```